# PHP: Create JSON from MySql to look like this. Consume in Swift 3

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array, swift3

My query is:

```
"SELECT day, title, speaker, time, room, details FROM classes"
```

I would love to know how to create JSON to look exactly like this from a MySql table in PHP:

```
{
   "DAY" : "MONDAY": [
             {
             "TITLE": "TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT",
             "SPEAKER": "JASON SHAPIRO",
             "TIME": "9:00 AM",
             "ROOM": "MATISSE",
             "DETAILS": "EXPLORE THE TOPICS AND TOOLS RELATED TO TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT."
             },
             {
             "TITLE": "JAVA TOOLS",
             "SPEAKER": "JIM WHITE",
             "TIME": "9:00 AM",
             "ROOM": "ROTHKO",
             "DETAILS": "DISCUSS THE LATEST SET OF TOOLS USED TO HELP EASE SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT."
             }
             ],
  "DAY" : "TUESDAY": [
             {
             "TITLE": "MONGODB",
             "SPEAKER": "DAVINMICKELSON",
             "TIME": "1: 00PM",
             "ROOM": "PICASSO",
             "DETAILS": "LEARNABOUT\"NOSQL\"DATABASES."
             },
             {
             "TITLE": "DEBUGGINGWITHXCODE",
             "SPEAKER": "JASONSHAPIRO",
             "TIME": "1: 00PM",
             "ROOM": "VANGOGH",
             "DETAILS": "EXPLOREDIFFERENTPATTERNSFORDEBUGGINGYOURIOSAPPS."
             }
             ],
             [
    Day etc....
             ]
  }
```

I am assuming I can't get this to work because of the word "DAY:" prior to the actual day.  But how would I consume this in Swift 3 being each day is dynamically generated? My ultimate goal is to create properly formatted JSON and consume it efficiently in Swift 3 tableview (for the days - vertically scrolled) and collection view (for the titles - horizontally scrolled in each table row).

Comment: This JSON is not valid. It looks like you are building this manually. Instead you should create arrays of associative arrays in PHP and then use `json_encode` to build the JSON. If you're having trouble with that, I'd suggest you first post a PHP question, with PHP code, on how to create JSON correctly. Only once you have that working should you worry about how to consume it properly in Swift. Until that point, I'd suggest you just delete this question to avoid getting further down-votes on this.

Comment: As an aside, dictionaries are (a) unordered and (b) must have unique keys. So this concept of having a key, `DAY`, repeated in a dictionary is a non-starter, as is the concept of having a series of keys representing a series of days (because you have no guarantee what order they'll be). I'd suggest a simple array of dictionaries. Something like: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/317d033bd1d132ecb17f59f53bc2d676.

Comment: By the way, tools like http://jsonlint.com are very useful in validating your JSON.

Comment: Thanks Rob...honestly don't care about down votes...really just looking for help.  What you produced on Github looks good

Answer (score 0):

Using same key in JSON will cause unintended result.

Below is valid JSON Formation.

```
{
   "MONDAY": [
             {
             "TITLE": "TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT",
             "SPEAKER": "JASON SHAPIRO",
             "TIME": "9:00 AM",
             "ROOM": "MATISSE",
             "DETAILS": "EXPLORE THE TOPICS AND TOOLS RELATED TO TEST DRIVEN DEVELOPMENT."
             },
             {
             "TITLE": "JAVA TOOLS",
             "SPEAKER": "JIM WHITE",
             "TIME": "9:00 AM",
             "ROOM": "ROTHKO",
             "DETAILS": "DISCUSS THE LATEST SET OF TOOLS USED TO HELP EASE SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT."
             }
             ],
  "TUESDAY": [
             {
             "TITLE": "MONGODB",
             "SPEAKER": "DAVINMICKELSON",
             "TIME": "1: 00PM",
             "ROOM": "PICASSO",
             "DETAILS": "LEARNABOUT\"NOSQL\"DATABASES."
             },
             {
             "TITLE": "DEBUGGINGWITHXCODE",
             "SPEAKER": "JASONSHAPIRO",
             "TIME": "1: 00PM",
             "ROOM": "VANGOGH",
             "DETAILS": "EXPLOREDIFFERENTPATTERNSFORDEBUGGINGYOURIOSAPPS."
             }
             ],
             [
    Day etc....
             ]
  }
```

create a sort function

```
// create a sort function
// put the whole result array to res
function sortResultByDay($res) {
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($res as $row) {
        $day = $row['day'];
        unset($row['day']);
        $returnArray[$day][] = $row;
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

and use the function like this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT day, title, speaker, time, room, details FROM classes");
$resArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    $resArray[] = $row;

$resArraySorted = sortResultByDay($resArray);
echo json_encode($resArraySorted);
```